# Why does jQuery.remove() remove mousedown listener from other div element?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, listener, mousedown

I'm working on a HTML5 friendly drag and drop system and I've encountered another mystery that seems to make no sense...

The system is working in Edge - it's when I'm emulating IE8 that I encounter this latest problem.

I have a set of '.draggable' divs that get the following listener attached:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reset-button').click(resetDraggables);
    if (!dragAndDropSupported()) {
        var $draggables = $('.draggable');
        $draggables.each( function (index) {
            $(this).mousedown( jQueryStartDrag );
        });               
    }
}
```

The draggables can be sent back to their original locations by hitting a 'reset' button. That all works fine.

The problem is - any divs that get sent back to their origins are no longer draggable. Even if I re-attach the listener in the reset function, it does not fire. Once again, this issue is only happening when I'm emulating IE8 and I don't remove the listener anywhere in my code.

```
function resetDraggables() {
    if ( !$('#reset-button').hasClass('inactive') ) {
        var $dropTargets = $('.drop-target');
        $dropTargets.each(function (index) {
            var draggableId = $(this).attr('data-contains');
            var $originDraggable = $('#' + draggableId);
            if ($originDraggable.attr('id')!=undefined) {
                var $droppedDraggable = $(this).find('.draggable');
                $droppedDraggable.remove();
                $originDraggable.removeClass('inactive').addClass('draggable').attr('draggable', 'true').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=100)').hide().fadeIn('fast');
                $('#' + draggableId).mousedown( jQueryStartDrag );
                $(this).removeClass('occupied').attr('data-contains', '');
                $('#reset-button').addClass('inactive');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've realised it's the $droppedDraggable.remove() line that's causing the problem. I'm not sure why a line to remove ONE object would remove the listener from another. The $droppedDraggable object was cloned from the other; Is that causing the issue?

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I replaced the jQuery remove() lines with...

```
var droppedDraggable = document.getElementById('dropped-' + draggableId);
droppedDraggable.outerHTML = "";
```

...and that has done the trick. I'm guessing there must have been some hidden association made between the objects when one was cloned from the other and remove()ing one removed the mousedown listener from the other.

If anyone has a better theory, feel free to let me know, but this seems to have solved the problem.

**Edit**
I've just realised the above fixed the problem in IE8, but not in 9. Great! If anyone has any pointers on how NOT to include a bunch of browser-specific work arounds in my code, I'd be very keen to hear them. Thanks.